# How does node resolve a module location when its required from another module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following directories and files

```
/path/to/dir1
/path/to/dir1/server.js
/path/to/dir1/package.json
/path/to/dir1/node_modules

/path/to/dir2/moduleA.js
```

Then I have moduleA.js which starts like this:

```
var React = require('react');
```

And my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Now from within server.js if I do this:

require('../dir2/moduleA')

It will find moduleA but then in moduleA I have require('react') which actually resides within the same directory of server.js in the node_modules folder. However this location is not searched and I am getting an error

Error: Cannot find module 'react'

I thought one of the locations searched when resolving require statements was the node_modules directory of the currently executing process? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 14):

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> ### Loading from `node_module`s Folders
>
> If the module identifier passed to `require()` is not a native module, and does not begin with `'/'`, `'../'`, or `'./'`, then node starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds `/node_modules`, and attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the tree is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at `'/home/ry/projects/foo.js'` called `require('bar.js')`, then node would look in the following locations, in this order:
>
> ```
> /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js
> /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
> /home/node_modules/bar.js
> /node_modules/bar.js
> ```
>
> This allows programs to localize their dependencies, so that they do not clash.

I.e. it would look in `/path/to/dir2/node_modules`, `/path/to/node_modules`, etc, but not in `/path/to/dir1/node_modules`.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway to set NODE_PATH as an environment variable to force it to search /path/to/dir1/node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought one of the locations searched when resolving require statements was the node_modules directory of the currently executing process?

No; `require` searches the `node_modules` in the same directory as the file containing the running the `require`, and all its parents. So a `require` in `/path/to/dir2/moduleA.js` searches:

- `/path/to/dir2/node_modules/`
- `/path/to/node_modules/`
- `/path/node_modules/`
- `/node_modules/`

The right way to do this is, in `/path/to/dir2`, assuming `dir2` is a complete module:

```
sudo npm link
```

Then back in `dir1`:

```
npm link dir2
```

And specify your dependencies properly for each one.

Comment: has it always been this way? i'm deploying on an old machine that is running 0.10.x and it seems to by pulling a package from a completely different path instead of the one in a node_modules directory directly an ancestor of the path the file is being required from...

Comment: @Michael: Pretty sure it has. When I answered this, 0.10 was the current version. You might want to ask a new question about that.